# Best Way to Hexdump Shellcode

Tags: hexdump

I'm trying to get shellcode from some programs I wrote.  Besides taking the hex code from an `objdump -D shellcode`, is there a better way to purely hexdump a string?  I've thrown it through hexdump as well, but that spits out way too many lines, and as it stands I don't know how to specify it to give me just the section of machine code after `_start`.

Comment: Are you asking about hexdumping a string or hexdumping shellcode? Please provide a short sample program and specify exactly what you're trying to get the hex for.

Comment: Hexdumping a program?  So shellcode?